# Nested List JSON Parse in Oracle PLSQL Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, jsonparser

--SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

```
DECLARE
    p_json                 CLOB := '
  {
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAMkADFjOTE3MDZmLTY3YWMtNDA0ZS05OWNmLWNmM",
            "ccRecipients": [
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "Sudip Dutta",
                        "address": "duttasudip89@gmail.com"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "D Roy",
                        "address": "Droy@gmail.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'
    ;
    l_cc_email_address     VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_cc_email_addresses   VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_message_id           VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    apex_json.parse(p_json);
    FOR cc_email_counter IN 1..apex_json.get_count(p_path => 'value.ccRecipients') LOOP
        l_cc_email_address := NULL;
        l_cc_email_address := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 
           'value[%d].ccRecipients[%d].emailAddress.address', p0 => cc_email_counter
        );
        dbms_output.put_line('New Iteration l_cc_email_addresses   :-   ' || l_cc_email_address);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I am trying to parse above json and want to print "address" tag value in loop. Not not able to do the same. Above code I tried.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"value" is an array of elements [] with a single element inside it - you need to pick the first array element in your `apex_json.get_count` function.

```
set serveroutput on size 999999
clear screen
DECLARE
  l_json_text CLOB;
  l_json_values    apex_json.t_values;

BEGIN 
l_json_text := '
  {
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAMkADFjOTE3MDZmLTY3YWMtNDA0ZS05OWNmLWNmM",
            "ccRecipients": [
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "Sudip Dutta",
                        "address": "duttasudip89@gmail.com"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "D Roy",
                        "address": "Droy@gmail.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
';

  apex_json.parse(
    p_values => l_json_values,
    p_source => l_json_text
  );

  FOR r IN 1 .. APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'value[1].ccRecipients', p_values => l_json_values) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('email address: '||apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'value[1].ccRecipients[%d].emailAddress.address', p0 => r, p_values => l_json_values));
  END LOOP;

END;
/

email address: duttasudip89@gmail.com
email address: Droy@gmail.com
```

Comment: Please mark question as answered if this solved your issue. That is the best way in stack overflow to say "thanks"